# REST API endpoint v1/carts/{cartId}/items always returns error message

Tags: magento2, quote, quoteitem, rest-api

Background: I'm doing all the following with an admin token, and I'm not dealing with guest carts.  There are quote_item records associated with the quote in question.  I've tried this with several different quote_id's, and they all behave in exactly the same way.

If I make a GET request to v1/carts/55402, I receive a correct response including the cart info, customer info, etc.

If I make a GET request to v1/carts/55402/**items**, I always get this error:

```
array (
  'message' => 'No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue',
  'parameters' => 
  array (
    'fieldName' => 'cartId',
    'fieldValue' => 55402,
  ),
)
```

Yet, if I go look in the quote_item table there are definitely items in that table that have a quote_id of 55402.

As I mentioned, this is the case for every quote I've tried via the API.  I can retrieve the quote, but **NOT** the quote items.

What am I doing wrong?